# Filtering File Paths Using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, regex, filtering, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array of file paths of the format [number]_[number].png
and get only the ones starting with a specific number, say 1.

This is what I tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"self MATCHES '%@/1_[0-9]+.png'",
                            [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"]];

NSArray *files = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png"
                                         inDirectory:@"Images"] 
                     filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I get an empty array.
I tried using LIKE instead of MATCHES. I tried using the [cd] flags though it shouldn't matter. Still I always get an empty array.
Is it something with the regular expression?

---

Edit:

It seems like the problem was with predicateWithFormat.

I thought it gets a format string followed by the arguments to substitute into the format string. It doesn't work like that. It ignores the arguments and nothing gets substituted in the format string.

So the solution is as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"self MATCHES '%@/1_[0-9]+.png'",
                           [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"]]];

NSArray *files = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png"
                                         inDirectory:@"Images"] 
                    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is a conflict between your first and second lines of code. The first line sets your `NSPredicate` so it is formatted like this:

```
Images/1_#.png
```

In your second line, you tell iOS to look for your predicate inside of the `Images` directory. By doing this, your final predicate / path looks like this:

```
Images/Images/1_#.png
```

Remove the part of the `NSPredicate` that appends the `Images/` directory to the beginning of the predicate.

The issue I describe above may not be the problem though. Another possible problem with the code is that your format for the predicate is not correct. In your original code, you forget to add the `+` after the `1` in your NSPredicate (you did it after the `[0-9]` but not the `1`).

Your code should look something like this:

```
NSString *filter = @"1+_[0-9]+.png";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self MATCHES %@", filter];
NSArray *files = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

When I test the code above in my application the NSPredicate successfully filters an NSString.

You might also want to have a look at this link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/07/27/filtering-arrays-with-nspredicate.html

Comment: @Ata01 Yes, `MATCHES` is what you are looking for in this scenario. I have edited my answer - please check the edited code at the end. I've also added another possible explanation.

Comment: I've tried the predicate with the plus sign after the '1' and without it and it doesn't work in both cases. I don't think using the plus sign is correct in my case since I need exactly one appearance of the digit '1', not one or more. I tried using the code you linked to and it does work, but there it only takes the file names and does the filtering on them. So I can do it like that. Strip the paths, filter the file names then add the full paths back, but if it's possible I'd like to do the filtering on the full paths.